# Can't figure out what is wrong with this switch statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this switch statement to work, but I keep getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error... I was under the impression that javascript switch statements can process strings?

```
swtich(opcode)
    {
        case "A9":  loadAccImmediate();     break;
        case "AD":  loadAccDirect();        break;
        case "8D":  storeAccInMem();        break;
        case "6D":  addWithCarry();         break;
        case "A2":  loadXRegWithConst();    break;
        case "AE":  loadXRegFromMem();      break;
        case "A0":  loadYRegWithConst();    break;
        case "AC":  loadYRegFromMem();      break;
        case "EA":  noOperation();          break;
        case "00":  sysBreak();             break;
        case "EC":  compareXReg();          break;
        case "D0":  branchXBytes();         break;
        case "EE":  incByteValue();         break;
        case "FF":  sysCall();              break;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: check the spelling of switch.

Comment: You forgot the `deflaut` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled `switch`:

```
swtich(opcode)
  ↑↑
```

Comment: wow, slaved for a half hour trying to figure out why it wouldn't accept my strings... THANK YOU